# Load Contents Into Primefaces Schedule

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would like to have an schedule in which all users can leave 'public' messages to each other. Here's the xhtml for my schedule

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <div id="dashboardMain">
        <h:form id="form">  

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />  

            <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleManager.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" aspectRatio="2" showWeekends="false" rightHeaderTemplate="false">  
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleManager.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />  
                <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleManager.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />  
            </p:schedule>  

            <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="#{msg['title.eventDetails']}" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">  
                <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails">
                    <p:row>  
                        <p:inputTextarea id="title" value="#{scheduleManager.event.title}" required="true" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="100"/>
                    </p:row>  

                    <p:row>
                    <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" process="@form" actionListener="#{scheduleManager.addEvent}" oncomplete="myschedule.update();eventDialog.hide();"/>  
                    <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" value="Delete" process="@form" actionListener="#{scheduleManager.deleteEvent}" oncomplete="myschedule.update();eventDialog.hide();"/>
                    </p:row>  
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:dialog>  
        </h:form>  
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

Here's the entity message that is being saved in the database everytime someone adds a new message in the schedule

```
@Entity(name = "schedule_message")
public class ScheduleMessage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "schedule_message_id")
    private Integer scheduleMessageId;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column
    private String message;

    public Integer getScheduleMessageId() {
        return scheduleMessageId;
    }

    public void setScheduleMessageId(Integer schedulerMessageId) {
        this.scheduleMessageId = schedulerMessageId;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

The messages are being stored fine. The problem is that I don't know how to load them.
Now, my question is: how can I load all the scheduleMessages (each one contains id, startDate, endDate and the actual message) and display them in the p:schedule?

Comment: Try to call update on schedule widgetwar like scheduler1.update() after saving the records

Comment: @rcompanhoni Do you want to show messages with `p:growl`? Or just want to show them as events?

Comment: @Ömer Faruk Almalı Yes, I would like to show them as events.

Comment: take every message and add to eventModel.addEvent as in this [Primefaces Schedule showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf)

Comment: @rcompanhoni If my answer didn't help, I can help or alter the answer?